# get connection ip into the html5 code

Tags: html, websocket, ip

i'm just starting web programing and i need a little help getting my connected ip into the html code.

im connecting to a server, e.g. `192.168.0.1:8080` via web browser. now the page i call there needs to connect to a websocket, which lays on that server, so the html code needs to be `connect(ws://192.168.0.1:9000)` for example.

is there a command to get the ip i entered in the web browser and use it in the code?
i want to have it like `connect(ws://get_ip_from_browser:9000)`, im sure you know what i mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that information I'd use `location.hostname`. Depending on what you enter to the URL, it will return either the server's hostname or ip.

```
   var ws_url = "ws://"+location.hostname+"9000"
   console.log(ws_url)
```